# font-awesome-4 Set star filled and make persistent on click (Start Rating System)

Tags: javascript, css, font-awesome

The [CSS for 5 Star Rating System](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23856153/3422102) is not a duplicate -- it uses jquery -- I don't.

I don't dabble much in web design, but found myself in need of a simple start rating system. I've sussed out how to make the star style persistent capturing the user-selection, but cannot figure out how to set the `style.content` responding to `onclick()`. The frustrating part is I can set the desired content using the `:hover` property, but in the JS function that responds to `onclick()` I can't make that style permanent.

The stars are properly styled from open (unfilled - glyph `"\f006"`) to filled (glyph `"\f005"`) on `:hover` and `:before` using a combination of the *child* and *general sibling* combinators (borrowed from the [FA4 Examples (Custom CSS)](https://fontawesome.com/v4/examples/) page). The page shows how to display the styled stars, but provides nothing on the selection or making the selection style persistent `onclick()`. I have the selection logic done, I just can't get the selected stars to stay filled.

Here is my MCVE/MRE (whatever the latest is):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>

/* CSS star rating system */
.rating {
  unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
  direction: rtl;
}

.rating > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 1.1em;
}

.rating > span:hover:before,
.rating > span:hover ~ span:before {
   content: "\f005";
   color: #DFB63C;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  <p>Star Rating (HowTo make :hover solid star persistent on click?)</p>
  <span class="rating">
    <span id="star5" class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" onclick="showrating(5)"></span><span id="star4" class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" onclick="showrating(4)"></span><span id="star3" class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" onclick="showrating(3)"></span><span id="star2" class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" onclick="showrating(2)"></span><span id="star1" class="fa fa-star-o fa-2x" onclick="showrating(1)"></span>
  </span>
</div>

</body>
</html> 

<script>

var rating_last = 0;

function showrating(n)
{
  alert ("rating: " + n);
  
  /* restore original star style if lower selection made later */
  while (rating_last > n) {
    let id = "star" + rating_last;
    let star = document.getElementById(id);
    star.style.content = "\f006";
    star.style.color = "#2E3436";
    rating_last--;
  }
  rating_last = n;
  
  /* set style for selected stars to show persistent selection */
  while (n) {
    let id = "star" + n;
    let star = document.getElementById(id);
    star.style.content = "\f005";
    star.style.color = "#DFB63C";
    n--;
  }
}

</script>
```

I have also tried creating a `.class` style and using the `.classList.replace()`, `.classList.add()` and `.classList.remove()` in lieu of the separate `.content` and `.color` styling without any success, e.g. (non-working attempts shown commented)

```css
.rating-on {
   content: "\f005";
   color: #DFB63C;
}
```

and

```js
var rating_last = 0;

function showrating(n)
{
  alert ("rating: " + n);
  
  while (rating_last > n) {
    let id = "star" + rating_last;
    let star = document.getElementById(id);
    star.style.content = "\f006";
    star.style.color = "#2E3436";
    /*
    star.classList.replace ("fa fa-star fa-2x", "fa fa-star-o fa-2x");
    star.classList.remove ("rating-on");
    */
    rating_last--;
  }
  rating_last = n;
  
  while (n) {
    let id = "star" + n;
    let star = document.getElementById(id);
    star.style.content = "\f005";
    star.style.color = "#DFB63C";
    /*
    star.classList.replace ("fa fa-star-o fa-2x", "fa fa-star fa-2x");
    star.classList.add ("rating-on");
    */
    n--;
  }
}
```

What bit of DOM/CSS/JS magic am I missing to be able to set the stars filled in the `showrating()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

The key was to use `.classList.replace()`, but not with the entire combined class string, but using only the style class representing the font-awesome glyph. The following accomplishes all goals:

```js
<script>

var rating_last = 0;

function showrating(n)
{
  alert ("rating: " + n);
  
  /* restore original star style if lower selection made later */
  while (rating_last > n) {
    let id = "star" + rating_last;
    let star = document.getElementById(id);
    star.classList.replace ("fa-star", "fa-star-o");
    star.style.color = "#2E3436";
    rating_last--;
  }
  rating_last = n;
  
  /* set style for selected stars to show persistent selection */
  while (n) {
    let id = "star" + n;
    let star = document.getElementById(id);
    star.classList.replace ("fa-star-o", "fa-star");
    star.style.color = "#DFB63C";
    n--;
  }
}

</script>
```